# java: super.clone() with Jackon ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

So I understand when implementing the `clone()` method, that you should first call `super.clone()` so the (potential) super class can do its thing and then do your own cloning. This all makes sure that not variables from the superclass are list / not cloned.

What now if I use Jacksons ObjectMapper to do the cloning:
`return objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this), Mail.class);`
I decided to do this as my object (`Mail`) was already fully convertible to and from json which is basically cloning anyways.
In this case calling super.clone() is useless right? Jackson will make a copy of the super variables anyways when it is set up that way so the result of `super.clone()` doesn't do anything.

Am I missing somthing here?

Greets,
Chris

Comment: You don't need to call `super.clone()` if you're not going to use the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `clone` method and Jackson are not related in any way. So you do not even need to implement a `clone` method.

Serializing and deserializing objects has always been a common approach to copy objects. Just keep in mind that it comes with downsides as well.

Answer (score 3):

> In this case calling super.clone() is useless right?

Not quiet. `Jackson` will do everything behind the scenes to correctly instantiate your object but only based on the **public** fields or those which you've configured to be serializable to JSON. **Information about the private fields will be lost**.

```
class A {
   public int x = 10;
   private int y = 100; // this info will be lost when cloning with Jackson
}
```

While this method is perfectly workable on small projects. I think, it will generate too much overhead if you use it as a clone method on a large one. Too much deserealisation and serialisation can get expensive.

You should consider using the [proxy pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pattern-prototype) to implement cloning in java. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy) can also help.

Comment: @Chris If this has solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as accepted. If something is still missing let me know and we can work on it.

Comment: The Prototy pattern (first link) describes the pattern which then uses the copy constructor to create a copy (which seems redundant when I already have json serialization set up for other uses). The second link is basically where I have the jackson serialization from. When I just work with a simple Model object, that gets de-/serialized to json for other use cases all the time anyway, then there shouldn't be an issue and then there is not reason to call super.clone(), right?